# How to access Flash drives in CLI mode?

Tags: command-line, usb-drive

I have fedora 20 64bit and for unknown reason I cannot boot on graphical mode.

I have very important files for my project there. How can I copy those files to my USB flash ? How can I find my USB in the text mode ?

Comment: `lsblk` if installed, or `blkid` with `sudo` or by *root*. You can use `parted -l` or `fdisk -l` same by *root*.

Comment: What is the Runlevel? If it is in 3 change it to 5.

Comment: @Savvy - I don't know what you mean?

Comment: @Costas - lsblk shows me the sdb, but it does not show the path to it

Comment: It will be mouch better if you post `lsblk` output... But in any way you can `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt -o uid=$(id -u),rw` and find out your USB flash at `mnt`

Comment: RubanSavvy suspects that you can't boot to a GUI because of an incorrect [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel). If you'd like to fix that, start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to indetify the usb disk by using `blkid` `lsblk` as Costas said and after that you will need to mount the volume (in read/write) if it is not mounted yet you can mount it under `/mnt/`for example. after that you will be able to copy your files into your usb key if you have some issue don't hesitate to paste output of dmesg , syslog's, ...

Cheers.